# When should I use multiple constructors?

Tags: vb.net, constructor

What is the difference between these two options?

**First Option - Multiple Constructors**

```
Public Sub New(Some parameters)
    'Do somthing
End Sub

Public Sub New(Other parameters)
    'Do something
End Sub
```

In this case, we use multiple constructors with different parameters in order to initialize different objects or to create an instance of a class in different ways.

**Second Option - Using Optional Parameters**

```
Public Sub New(Optional some values)
    'Do something
End Sub
```

In this case, we use `Optional` parameters only when we want to assign them.By using this method we can control which objects we want to initialize or create an instance of them.

Comment: sometimes how your class is used dictates the number and type of ctors.  A collection editor, for instance, requires a simple constructor, but then for Designer Serialization, you might need one which takes certain params to use in a TypeConverter; then you might use yet another one in code to minimize explicit property setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are using method overloading to invoke different functionality in different constructors based on the method signature.  That functionality might include allowing some parameters to assume default values.

Using optional parameters is more appropriate in a constructor when you *only* want some parameters to be optional and you're not looking to invoke different *functionality* in the constructor, other than allowing some parameters to be set by default if you don't supply them.

Comment: I believe that isn't a polymoprhism case. It's constructor/method overloading.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: Yes, that's what I said.  Method polymorphism.   See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)#Ad_hoc_polymorphism

Comment: Maybe I'm absolutely wrong, but overloading != polymorphism. If you say polymorphism, you should be talking about how inherited classes are able to override base's implementations rather than the chance of having a method with different parameter sets!!

Comment: There are different kinds of polymorphism.  Read the Wikipedia article I linked.

Comment: Even if Wikipedia says that, I'm not agree to call overloading as *polymorphism* even if there they call it *parametric polymorphism*. I just wanted to point out that calling it *overloading* would make things easier, because you won't search for "method polymorphism" on MSDN to get further info about this topic...

Comment: Polymorphism is not used when you want to create an instance of a class? i.e Dim Foo As SomeClass=New SomeClass

Comment: @ILoveMom Polymorphism would be an up/downcast: `Dim Foo As BaseClass = New DerivedClassOfBaseClass` (it's just a sample)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I changed the wording to satisfy you.  As you can see, it required more words to get it right.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would invite you to a beer, but my guess is we're too far... But thanks! Even if it took more words, now is a more ".NET-style" answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that...

### ... constructor overloading is used when:

*Class may be initialized using different parameters, but possible combinations of the whole arguments is limited and they're mandatory depending on the available class initialization use cases.*

### ... optional parameters are used when:

*Class may be initialized or not with some arguments. None of them are mandatory, and some or all may be provided, with no negative effect depending on which parameters have received arguments*.